# Special Transition/Effect on the AppStore on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, transition, effect

I want to know if there is a Library that produces the same effect as we have on the AppStore when we view an app and see the details of the app.

I want to use it on my iPad application.

(If you want to see the effect,  it's only available on iPad)

Comment: I think you're talking about the appStore and not the Apple Store ;)

Comment: yes i talk about the appStore sorry

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/) may help.

As well as [This](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/ios-7-custom-transitions/).

And [This](http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/ios-7-custom-view-controller-transitions-and-rotation-making-it-all-work)

The thing you want to use for this purpose is the `UIViewController Transitioning API` introduced in iOS7

There are plenty tutorial on custom transition in the web. (see the links)